# what is the difference between these web development languages?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I know this is a huge noob question, but I will ask it anyways. What is the difference between all of these web development languages. Like what is the difference between java script and Google App engine? When would you use each of them? What about Jason what is the use for that? Do most of these languages do the same thing or do they all have different uses? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that qualify as language among all those you mentioned is Javascript. JSON is a javascript object notation. It's tool but not a language itself.

Google app engine is a framework on top of programming languages to create cloud based services.

[**JSON**](http://www.json.org/)

> :(JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999. JSON is a text format that is completely language independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, and many others. These properties make JSON an ideal data-interchange language.

[**Javascript**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

> : (often shortened to JS) is a lightweight, interpreted, object-oriented language with first-class functions, most known as the scripting language for Web pages, but used in many non-browser environments as well such as node.js or Apache CouchDB. It is a prototype-based, multi-paradigm scripting language that is dynamic, is type safe, and supports object-oriented, imperative, and functional programming styles.

[**Google App Engine**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine)

> Google App Engine lets you run web applications on Google's infrastructure. App Engine applications are easy to build, easy to maintain, and easy to scale as your traffic and data storage needs grow. With App Engine, there are no servers to maintain: You just upload your application, and it's ready to serve your users.
>
> You can serve your app from your own domain name (such as http://www.example.com/) using Google Apps. Or, you can serve your app using a free name on the appspot.com domain. You can share your application with the world, or limit access to members of your organization.
>
> Google App Engine supports apps written in several programming languages. With App Engine's Java runtime environment, you can build your app using standard Java technologies, including the JVM, Java servlets, and the Java programming language - or any other language using a JVM-based interpreter or compiler, such as JavaScript or Ruby. App Engine also features a Python runtime environment, which includes a fast Python interpreter and the Python standard library. App Engine also features a PHP runtime, with native support for Google Cloud SQL and Google Cloud Storage that works just like using a local mySQL instance and doing local file writes. Finally, App Engine provides a Go runtime environment that runs natively compiled Go code. These runtime environments are built to ensure that your application runs quickly, securely, and without interference from other apps on the system.

Comment: This question (and answer) should not be part of this forum. Read the faq.